# print parentNode until body

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code:

```
<body onMouseDown="javaScript:mouseEventHandler(event);">
   <div id="hello">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Hi friends</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
   </div>
   <div id="result">
    <ul id="ularraydom">
    </ul>
   </div>
```

I need to get in a new div called result as i showed, an array of td's parentNodes until I get BODY.

The result should be like this:

```
<ul id="ularraydom">
<li>TD</li> 
<li>TR</li> 
<li>TABLE</li> 
<li>DIV</li> 
<li>BODY</li>
</ul>
```

I tried with:

```
function mouseEventHandler(mEvent)
{
  // Internet Explorer
 if (mEvent.srcElement)
   {
    alert(mEvent.srcElement.nodeName);
   }
 // Netscape and Firefox
 else if (mEvent.target)
   {
    var ularraydom = document.getElementById("ularraydom");
    ularraydom.innerHTML = "<li>" + mEvent.target.parentNode.nodeName; + "</li>";
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's the problem with the code you tried? What is the result you get?

Comment: @Felix Kling the result i get is just one row, and if i want all the rows, i need to put parentNode + parentNode ...... the whole time. The point is that i want to fix this with a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recursion is your friend:

```js
function printNode(node){
  var ularraydom = document.getElementById("ularraydom");
  ularraydom.innerHTML += "<li>" + node.nodeName; + "</li>"; // be aware of the += !

  if(node.nodeName !== "BODY"){
    printNode(node.parentNode); //recursion!
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div id="hello">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td onclick="printNode(this)">click here</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
   </div>
   <div id="result">
    <ul id="ularraydom">
    </ul>
   </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Upwards traversal is pretty straightforward:

```
var node = mEvent.target.parentNode;
while (node && node.nodeName !== 'HTML') {
    // print node.nodeName ...

    node = node.parentNode; // up
}
```